# Samsung touchscreen lms430hf12-003 - can this be used with the raspberry pi ?

Tags: touchscreen

Ok so I am trying to find a solution for a LCD for my PI and I had this old Garmin sitting around and so I thought I would see if I can use the display for PI, I am sure that it can work, but I just not sure if I will need anything else to get it to work, are there specific drivers that I would need to get it to work? ANY help would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IT WONT WORK.

Raspberry Pi is not designed to be used with random LCD panels, that require a special driver IC most of the time. If your LCD panel does not include HDMI input or converter of some sort, it's very impractical and time consuming to try to connect this panel.

Comment: Agere.  If you did not know that you need special electronics for this, then you do not have the skill to make it work (I don't either).  A small monitor with dvi connector perhaps?

Comment: Also agree. See the connected question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/wire-raspberry-pi-to-7-tft-lcd/9338#9338